# How to set Gridview without using ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, gridview, android-arrayadapter

I have an array to display in GridView , I used ArrayAdapter to display the array elements in Gridview.

```
String [] abc={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};

  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=   new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,abc);

      gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

So , i got the array in GridView but i want to know how can we print an array in GridView without using ArrayAdapter.

Please help me out !!!! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why do you want to know it ?

Comment: its ok .dont take it personal